# dispatch_async内の処理について

Tags: swift

```
private var queue: dispatch_queue_t = dispatch_queue_create("test.test.testcall", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)

func test() {
    NSLog(（１）)
    dispatch_async(queue, {
        NSLog(（２）)
    })
}
```

（１）、（２）のログとして以下のようなログが出力されます。
[数字１:数字２]ログ

数字２についてはスレッドIDだと思うので、上記のような処理の場合、異なる値が出力されるものと考えているのですが、認識違いがありますでしょうか。

swift内で上記のようにすると、確かにログの「数字２」の部分は異なる値が出力されるのですが、

・swift
・C＋＋クラスを動かすためのObje-C＋＋
・C＋＋(拡張子はmm)
swift→Obje-C++→C++→Obje-C++→swiftの流れで処理させようとした際に、

・C＋＋クラスを動かすためのObje-C＋＋
ここで同じ処理を入れても、
（１）、（２）のログ「数字２」は同じものとなってしまい、よくわからなくなってしましました。。。
Obje-C++でも同じようにdispatch_async()を利用することでスレッドIDが変わるものと考えているのですが
異なるのでしょうか。
それとも、変わらないこともあるのでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 数字２についてはスレッドIDだと思うので、上記のような処理の場合、異なる値が出力されるものと考えているのですが、認識違いがありますでしょうか。

test()をqueueのスレッドで呼び出せば、(1),(2)は同じスレッドIDになるでしょうね。
試しに、(2)の箇所でtest()を呼び出してみましょう。（無限ループになりますが）

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！
確かにおっしゃる通りになりました。うう。。ということはどこかしらで同じqueueから呼び出していることになるのかもしれません。。。
処理を眺めまわしたいと思います！